# Static files getting 404 with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx

I have configured nginx to serve static page as below.

```
       location /home {
                alias /home/username/files/home;
                try_files $uri /home/index.html;
        }
```

Only index.html loads on `http://example.com/home`. All other css, js and image files are getting 404 as request is still going for `http://example.com/css/style.css` instead of `http://example.com/home/css/style.css`. Is there any way I can configure `/home` prefix to all the static file without manually adding to all static files?

Comment: Added important note to the answer, check the answer edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use variable root depending on HTTP `Referer` header (although it is a dirty hack):

```
map $http_referer $root {
    ~example\.com/home/    /home/username/files/home;
    default                <your default root here>;
}

server {
    ...
    root $root;

    location /home {
        root /home/username/files;
        try_files $uri /home/index.html;
    }
}
```

Note that if any of your web pages under `/home/` have a links to the main site, those links won't work correctly because of `example.com/home/...` HTTP Referer header value.

Why `root /home/username/files;` instead of `alias /home/username/files/home;`, you ask? Because as nginx documentation [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias):

> When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     alias /data/w3/images/;
> }
> ```
>
> it is better to use the `root` directive instead:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     root /data/w3;
> }
> ```

Comment: For now this hack works. Only link from `/home/` to the main site `example.com` itself.